# 「nをk個の相異なる数に分割する」場合の数を高速に求めるには？

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム, haskell

「nをk個の相異なる数に分割する」場合の数をf(n, k)とします。

例えば、10 = 1 + 2 + 7 = 1 + 3 + 6 = 1 + 4 + 5 = 2 + 3 + 5
なので、f(10, 3) = 4です。

f(n, k)を高速に求めるにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

以下大変遅いコードです。

```
# nをk個の相異なる数（最大値がl）に分割
def g(n, l, k)
  return 1 if n == l && k == 1
  # 末尾がiのものにlを追加
  (1..l - 1).inject(0){|s, i| s += g(n - l, i, k - 1)}
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, l| s += g(n, l, k)}
end

# 以下検証のためp(n | 和因子は相異なる)を求めてみる
def A000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += f(n, k)}
end
p (0..20).map{|i| A000009(i)}
```

実行結果
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 54, 64]
（p(n | 和因子は相異なる)については、[オイラーの分割恒等式をプログラミングで確認するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9548/%E3%82%AA%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86%E5%89%B2%E6%81%92%E7%AD%89%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%92%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A7%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF) で質問しました。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のコード中の`g_`はnをmin以上の相異なるk個の数を使って分割する場合の数を数え上げる関数です.
k個の相異なる数への分割(最小値l)を(l,...,m)と数の昇順に書くとすると,分割(l+1,...,m)に対して分割(l,...,m+1)が考えられるので,`g_`でのリストの走査において結果が0となるような要素が現れれば,それ以降のリストの走査を打ち切ることができます.

Ruby:

```
# nをmin以上の相異なるk個の数で分割
def g_(n, min, k)
  return 0 if n < min
  return 1 if k == 1
  sum = 0
  for l in (min..n)
    v = g_(n-l, l+1, k-1)
    break if v == 0
    sum += v
  end
  return sum
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  g_(n,1,k)
end

def A000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += f(n, k)}
end
p (0..20).map{|i| A000009(i)}
```

Haskell:

```
main = print $ map a000009' [1..20]

a000009' n = sum (map (\x -> f n x) [1..n])

f n k = g' n k 1

-- nを最小値min以上の相異なるk個の数で分割
g' n _ min
   | n < min = 0
g' n 1 min = 1
g' n k min = sum (mapUntil (==0) (\l -> g' (n-l) (k-1) (l+1)) [min..])

mapUntil pred f (x:rest) = let v = f x
                           in if pred v
                              then []
                              else v:mapUntil pred f rest
mapUntil _ _ [] = []
```

Comment: n = 50としてみたら、随分速いことが実感できました。

Answer (score 2):

数学の専門家ではないので、これがベストな解かは分かりませんが、ミリ秒レベルまでスピードアップできました。

`(1..n)`からk個選ぶ組み合わせを取得して、合計値がnになるものだけを数えています。
http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/array/combination
さらに探索の無駄を省くため、取りうる要素の最大値を最初に求めています。
例えば`f(10, 3)`を求める場合は、最大値7（1 + 2 + **7**）をまず求めて、`1..7`から３個選ぶ・・というような感じです。

```
# nをk個の相異なる数（最大値がl）に分割
def g(n, l, k)
  return 1 if n == l && k == 1
  # 末尾がiのものにlを追加
  (1..l - 1).inject(0){|s, i| s += g(n - l, i, k - 1)}
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, l| s += g(n, l, k)}
end

# 以下検証のためp(n | 和因子は相異なる)を求めてみる
def A000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += f(n, k)}
end

########## 以下を追加

def using_combination(n, k)
  max = n - ((1...k).inject(:+) || 0)
  (1..max).to_a.combination(k).count {|values| values.inject(:+) == n }
end

def B000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += using_combination(n, k)}
end

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm 20 do |r|
  result1, result2 = nil

  r.report 'Original' do
    result1 =  (0..20).map{|i| A000009(i)}
  end
  r.report 'UsingCombination' do
    result2 =  (0..20).map{|i| B000009(i)}
  end

  raise 'The results are NOT equal' if result1 != result2
  puts 'ok.'
end
```

実行結果

```
                           user     system      total        real
Original              21.390000   0.070000  21.460000 ( 21.508744)
UsingCombination       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005335)
ok.
```

Answer (score 1):

最大値ではなく、最小値に注目するとすぐに求まるようになりました。
（combinationを使うとnを大きくしたとき大変遅くなりますが、
以下のコードはそこまで遅くならない。例えば、n = 50としてみてください。）

```
# nをk個の相異なる数（最小値がl）に分割
def g0(n, l, k)
  return 1 if n == l && k == 1
  # 先頭がiのものにlを前から追加
  (l + 1..n - l).inject(0){|s, i| s += g0(n - l, i, k - 1)}
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, l| s += g0(n, l, k)}
end

# 以下検証のためp(n | 和因子は相異なる)を求めてみる
def A000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += f(n, k)}
end
p (0..20).map{|i| A000009(i)}
```

(追記)
蛇足かもしれませんが、
letrec さんの説明の補足と
letrec さんのコードを少しだけいじったものを
記しておきます。

[説明の補足]
nをl以上の相異なるk個の数で分割する場合の数をg1(n, l, k)とする。

これは、最小値がlのもの, l + 1のもの, l + 2のもの, … に分類できるので、
g1(n, l, k)
= g1(n - l, l + 1, k - 1) + g1(n - l - 1, l + 2, k - 1) + g1(n - l - 2, l + 3, k - 1) + …
となる。

また、
g1(n - l, l + 1, k - 1) ≧ g1(n - l - 1, l + 2, k - 1) ≧ g1(n - l - 2, l + 3, k - 1) ≧ …
となっている。
この理由は以下の通りです
a > 0 とする。
n - l - aのk'個の相異なる数への分割(最小値はl + a + 1以上)
(m1, … , mk')に対し、
(m1, … , mk' + 1)を作ると、
これはn - l - a + 1のk'個の相異なる数への分割(最小値l + a + 1以上)である。
当然、n - l - a + 1のk'個の相異なる数への分割(最小値l + a以上)になっている。
よって、
g1(n - l - a + 1, l + a, k - 1) ≧ g1(n - l - a, l + a + 1, k - 1)

よって、
g1(n - l, l + 1, k - 1), g1(n - l - 1, l + 2, k - 1), g1(n - l - 2, l + 3, k - 1), …
と計算していき、その結果が0となった時点で計算を打ち切ればよい。

さて、求めるべきf(n, k)はg1(n, 1, k)に他ならない。

[コード]

```
# nをl以上の相異なるk個の数で分割
def g1(n, l, k)
  return 0 if n < l
  return 1 if k == 1
  s = 0
  (l + 1..n).each{|i|
    v = g1(n - i + 1, i, k - 1)
    break if v == 0
    s += v
  }
  return s
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  g1(n, 1, k)
end

def A000009(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  (1..n).inject(0){|s, k| s += f(n, k)}
end
p (0..20).map{|i| A000009(i)}
```

(さらに追記)
再帰よりDP の方が速い。

```
def f1(n, k)
  a = []
  (k + 1).times{a << Array.new(n + 1){0}}
  a[0][0] = 1
  # 足し合わせる最大がx
  (1..n).each{|x|
    b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
    (1..k).each{|i| (0..n - x).each{|j| b[i][j + x] += a[i - 1][j]}}
    a = b
  }
  a[-1][-1]
end

p f1(200, 10)

# nをl以上の相異なるk個の数で分割
def g1(n, l, k)
  return 0 if n < l
  return 1 if k == 1
  s = 0
  (l + 1..n).each{|i|
    v = g1(n - i + 1, i, k - 1)
    break if v == 0
    s += v
  }
  return s
end

# nをk個の相異なる数に分割
def f(n, k)
  g1(n, 1, k)
end

p f(200, 10)
```

実行結果
98762607
98762607

Comment: なるほど。こっちの方がいいですね！